# HazelcastClient with fail-over Cluster for same HazelcastIstance

Tags: java, network-programming, cluster-computing, distributed-caching, hazelcast

Is it possible to configure a HazelcastClient with 2 different TCP/IP clusters for the same HazelcastInstance? (I have the split-brain syndrome and i want the second cluster to be a backup cluster).

I'm asking if it's possible for the same ClientConfig to specify 2 TCP/IP addresses (wich are indeed 2 different harware Virtual IP Addresses (VIPAs)) as if they were 2 simple cluster members pertaining to the same cluster group? I mean, is there any problem in specifying a single VIPA address instead of specifying all of the members IP addresses?

I thinks it would be better explained with an image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can but if you also need the data (of 2 clusters) to be synchronized then you should use wan-replication.
See:

http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.5/manual/single_html/#WanReplication

Comment: Thank you @javanes. Have you validated this scenario in any way? Kind regards.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't realized it was you ;) Anyway, it would be very interesting if hazelcast could support 2 separated list of (cluster) members IPs. With the above configuration, i'm obligated to use hardware VIPAs that couldn't possibly be available.